# ObjectiveC - displaying window through distributed objects

Tags: objective-c, rpc

I try to display window in other process using Distributed objects. 
Process A invoke remotely through Distributed Object method from process B which display dialog. Something wrong happens if I try to wait for results.
The method looks like that:

```
-(BOOL)showWindow  //method invoked through distributed objects
{    
    dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [object showDialog:^(BOOL result){ //this methods creates and display window 
         NSLog(@"Block called");
         dispatch_semaphor_signal(sem);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return YES;
}
```

The function showWindow never ends. If I comment dispatch_semaphore_wait "Block called" is displayed and window is show.
I checked different variant synchronization, I tried to run this code using dispatch_sync or async but nothing helped.

I will be gratefull for help. 
Kon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that DO requires that the run loop runs in order to process communication between the two sides. Basically, the code you showed sends a request to the remote side, the one which hosts the real object that `object` is a proxy for. The request carries a reference to your local block object. The remote side effectively gets a proxy for that.

Some time later, the remote side invokes its block proxy. That causes a request to be sent back to this process and thread. However, this thread can't receive that request because it is blocked in `dispatch_semaphore_wait()`. It is not attending to any communication channels.

So, both sides deadlock. The local side waits forever for a semaphore that will never be signaled and the remote side waits forever for its request to run the block to complete.

Thought of another way, the semaphore is **not** signaled by the remote process. You've asked for it to be signaled by this same thread which is waiting on it. It's just that, if it were possible, this thread would do so in response to an event sent by another process. Having a thread be responsible for signaling the semaphore that it's waiting on is a pretty clear, immediate self-deadlock.

Can you change `-showWindow` to not be synchronous? Why is it using a semaphore and waiting? Why can't it just fire off the request and then return back to the calling code, which should not assume the dialog has completed and instead return all the way back to the main event loop? Whatever work should happen "next" should be put into the completion block and will just be invoked asynchronously when the dialog completes.

If you really, really need this method to be synchronous, then you will have to use the run loop to wait instead of a dispatch semaphore. Something like:

```
-(BOOL)showWindow  //method invoked through distributed objects
{    
    __block BOOL done = NO;
    [object showDialog:^(BOOL result){ //this methods creates and display window 
         NSLog(@"Block called");
         done = YES;
    }];
    NSString* mode = @"com.yourcompany.yourapp.privatemode";
    NSConnection* conn = [(NSDistantObject*)object connectionForProxy];
    [conn addRequestMode:mode];
    while (!done)
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:mode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    [conn removeRequestMode:mode];
    return YES;
}
```

Probably, you should actually add the private mode to the connection when it's first created and leave it there for its lifetime. You don't want to use any of the predefined modes for this because then unexpected things may fire while you're waiting and your code becomes unexpectedly re-entrant, etc.